# Dendogram example seems incomplete?

Tags: d3.js, dendrogram

[In this d3.js example](http://strongriley.github.io/d3/ex/cluster.html) a dendogram is displayed.

Source code is posted but it seems incomplete? Can this dendogram be rendered in a fiddle? What is the data format for this example?

Comment: This link might be more helpful: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063570.

As for the data format: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4063550/flare.json

Comment: The data is in an external json file here: http://strongriley.github.io/d3/data/flare.json

Comment: @Towler thanks, that does offer more detail but where/how is the data for the dendogram being loaded?

Comment: @Towler I added comment before reading yours. Thanks ill try that

Comment: Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/drW3e/  Instead of loading the data from an external file, the data is returned by a `getData()` function.